# AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'get_place_trends Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I am using this to get a list of trending hashtag in twitter.

```
import tweepy
 
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
 
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
 
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
 
api = tweepy.API(auth)
 
woeid = 44418
trends = api.get_place_trends(id = woeid)
 
print("The top trends for the location are :")
 
for value in trends:
    for trend in value['trends']:
        print(trend['name'])
```

It is producing this error: `AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'get_place_trends'`. I looked at the documentation https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#get-trends-near-a-location But I am still unclear why I am getting this error. Could you please what this error means?

Comment: might be caused by the version of your package, it was called  by `API.trends_place` before (from the official doc : Changed in version 4.0: Renamed from API.trends_place). Try it with that old syntax it might resolve your issue.

Comment: Check what is your tweepy version. Is it before 4.0?

Comment: I think you can check the source code of your `API.trends_place` method. It often happen to be a package that can handle the object-oriented programming, and sometimes the APIs change unintentionally when you plainly upgrade them